# Deducing another type using trait

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I've some pre-existing classes like *Car, Train, CarWheel, TrainWheel* etc. These are coming from some library - so I can't modify those. Car and Train are not from any common base class. So are CarWheel and TrainWheel. Now, I'm trying to write templated function f() and facing challenge how to implement this **Trait< T >::WheelType** trait. Any pointer will help. This being a type, not a value, is creating confusion.

```
class Car {
public:
    // ....
    int       numWheels() const;
    CarWheel& getWheel(int i) const;
    void      print() const;
    // ...
};

class Train {
public:
    // ...
    int         numWheels() const;
    TrainWheel& getWheel(int i) const;
    void        print() const;
    // ...
};

template <typename T >
void  f(const T& obj) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.numWheels(); ++i) {
        Trait<T>::WheelType w(obj.getWheel(i));
        w.print();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Car c;
    f(c);

    Train t;
    f(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Trait<T>::WheelType w(obj.getWheel(i));` -> `auto& w = obj.getWheel(i);`

Comment: Thanks - I already did auto and it worked. But I wanted to *learn* if there's a way to define traits like this :)